# React is getting slower

Tags: reactjs

[image]

I am making a simple shopping mall using 'react router dome' and 'style component'.

However, when I was using the router to call other components, I noticed that they were initially fast, but they were slower and slower when I replaced them several times.

If you perform several changes to the component in the attached gif, the apple image component will appear immediately at first, but there will be a delay later. (It looks like there's no difference because it's a simple test code, but if you make it into a shopping mall, it feels like it's almost 0.5 seconds slower.)

How can i solve it?

It's only been a week since I learn React, so I don't know how to solve it or what the related issue keywords are.

Below is a simple test code, but it's a little long. Sorry

Thank you!

```
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import MainComponent from './component/MainComponent';
import ImageComponent from './component/ImageComponent';

function App() {

    const Wrapper = {
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'left',
    }

    const Header = {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: '0px',
        left: '500px',
        height: '100px',
    }

    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <div style={Wrapper}>
                <div style={Header}>
                    <Link to={'/'}><button>Main</button></Link>
                    <Link to={'/Image'}><button>Image</button></Link>
                </div>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/" element={<MainComponent/>} />
                    <Route path="/Image" element={<ImageComponent/>} />
                </Routes>
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}

export default App;
```

```
import styled from 'styled-components'

function MainComponent() {

    const MainComponent = styled.div `
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: red;
    `;
    
    return (
        <MainComponent>
            Main
        </MainComponent>
    )
}

export default MainComponent
```

```
import styled from 'styled-components'
import Image from './Image';

function ImageComponent() {

    const ImageComponent = styled.div `
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
        width: 100vw;
    `;
    
    return (
        <ImageComponent>
            <Image></Image>
            <Image></Image>
            <Image></Image>
            <Image></Image>
            <Image></Image>
            <Image></Image>
            <Image></Image>
            <Image></Image>
            <Image></Image>
            <Image></Image>
            <Image></Image>
            <Image></Image>
            <Image></Image>
            <Image></Image>
            <Image></Image>
            <Image></Image>
            <Image></Image>
            <Image></Image>
            <Image></Image>
            <Image></Image>
            <Image></Image>
            <Image></Image>
            <Image></Image>
            <Image></Image>
            <Image></Image>
            <Image></Image>
        </ImageComponent>
    )
}

export default ImageComponent
```

```
import styled from 'styled-components'
import React from 'react';

function Image() {

    const Image = styled.img `
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
    `;
    
    return (
        <Image src={`./Apple.png`}></Image>
    )
}

export default React.memo(Image)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that declaration using 'style component' in functional components slows down! I declared it outside, and there was no slowdown

Comment: Ofcourse. Do not create component inside another component. If necessary - always use useCallback